# How to create a unique account name collection variable in Salesforce flow?

Tags: visual-workflow

I want to create a unique account(unique account name) collection variable in Salesforce flow using the get record element, we have a duplicate account name(multiple accounts with the same name) and I want to skip the same name account in my collection variable.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Unique collections requires using advanced programming concepts like using `Sets` and `Maps`. These are not today supported out-of-box in Flows.

There is an [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dre0AAC) for this on IdeaExchange. Consider upvoting!

However, the community has done some open source work that you can adopt and experiment with.

There is a component [here](https://unofficialsf.com/list-actions-for-flow/) that you can install as an unmanaged [package](https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fpackaging%2FinstallPackage.apexp%3Fp0%3D04t5G0000047xI1QAI).

The [apex code](https://github.com/alexed1/LightningFlowComponents/blob/master/flow_action_components/CollectionProcessors/force-app/main/default/classes/DedupeRecordCollection.cls) for this is pretty simple and open-sourced as well and easy to understand if you are familiar with apex.

```
global with sharing class DedupeRecordCollection {

@InvocableMethod
global static List<FlowResponse> dedupe(List<FlowRequest> requests) {
    List<FlowResponse> flowResponses = new List<FlowResponse>();
    for (FlowRequest request : requests) {
        FlowResponse flowResponse = new FlowResponse();
        flowResponse.outputRecordCollection = getUniqueSObjectCollection(request);
        flowResponses.add(flowResponse);
    }
    return flowResponses;
}

private static List<SObject> getUniqueSObjectCollection(FlowRequest request) {
    Map<String, SObject> sobjectMap = new Map<String, SObject>();
    for (SObject record : request.inputRecordCollection) {
        try {
            String fieldValue = String.valueOf(record.get(request.fieldToDedupeOn));
            if(!sobjectMap.containsKey(fieldValue)) {
                sobjectMap.put(fieldValue, record);
            }
        } catch(SObjectException e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return sobjectMap.values();
}

global class FlowRequest {

    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global List<SObject> inputRecordCollection;
    
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global String fieldToDedupeOn;
    
}

global class FlowResponse {

    public FlowResponse() {
        outputRecordCollection = new List<SObject>();
    }

    @InvocableVariable
    global List<SObject> outputRecordCollection;

   }
 }
```